# How to pass along a generic?

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm fairly new to TypeScript, so I'm still trying to wrap my head around generics.

I have a class, `Client`, that has an `AxiosInstance` property. This is used to attach headers to each request.

I'd like the `Client` class to have the exact same `get` and `post` methods that an `AxiosInstance` has.

This is easy enough. I'll make it as simple as I can for this question:

```
import Axios, { type AxiosInstance, type InternalAxiosRequestConfig } from 'axios';

class Client {
  constructor(){
    this.axios = Axios.create();

    // Attach authorization to each request if it does not already exist.
    this.axios.interceptors.request.use((requestConfig: InternalAxiosRequestConfig) => {
      requestConfig.headers = {
        authorization: 'basic foobar',
        ...requestConfig.headers
      };

      return requestConfig;
    });
  }

  axios: AxiosInstance;

  get/*<What do I put here?>*/(...args: Parameters<AxiosInstance['get']>) {
    return this.axios.get/*<What do I put here?>*/(...args);
  }

  post/*<What do I put here?>*/(...args: Parameters<AxiosInstance['post']>) {
    return this.axios.post/*<What do I put here?>*/(...args);
  }
}
```

My question is, `AxiosInstance.get()` and `AxiosInstance.post` each have generics — am I even saying that correctly? How do I pass the generics, similar to how I've done with the args, from the `Client.get()` and `Client.post()` to the `AxiosInstance.get()` and `AxiosInstance.post()`?

Comment: Pretty sure the answer is simply `<T>` in all positions. What have you tried?

Comment: Please consider providing a [mre] that demonstrates your issue when we copy and paste it into our own IDEs.  Does the question actually depend on axios? Then you should probably tag it as such; if not, then you should probably remove any apparent dependency of your example code on it.  Either way, it would be helpful if your example code imports or declares any private or third party types so that others don't get errors unrelated to your question.

Comment: @Phil — When I hover over `this.axios.post()`, I see: `Axios.post<any, AxiosResponse<any, any>, unknown>()`. Would simply providing `<T>` only pass the first `any`? Sorry if it seems like a ridiculous question - generics confuse the hell outta me.

Comment: Try viewing the actual definition... `post<T = any, R = AxiosResponse<T>, D = any>(url: string, data?: D, config?: RawAxiosRequestConfig<D>): Promise<R>;`

Comment: Thanks, @Phil. I was just unaware if there was something similar to the `Parameters<AxiosInstance['post']>` that would just get them all. Cheers!

Comment: What benefit does your `Client` class provide over simply exporting the created Axios instance?

Comment: TS can't easily manipulate higher order generic types the way you want; `Parameters<F>` will erase all generic type parameters inside the `F` type.  You can get closer with instantiation expressions as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/m3vLbN), but that doesn't seem like a big win and in this case I'd be inclined to just copy the definitions from the index.d.ts file in axios and reuse them in your code as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mpxdbm).  Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @Phil — There's a lot more to `Client` and its `AxiosInstance`, I just didn't want to overcomplicate the question.

Comment: @jcalz — That's fantastic, thank you! I appreciate the links and your explanation!

Comment: @Stev your question is lacking information then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript lacks the ability to perform arbitrary higher-level type manipulation of the sort you'd need to write this easily.  In particular there's no way to use something like [the `Parameters<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype) on a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function type without losing information.  The generic type parameters will be replaced with their [constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) when you do that:

```
type GenFn = <A extends string, B extends number>(a: A, b: B) => [A, B];

type P = Parameters<GenFn>;
// type P = [a: string, b: number]
```

Oops, `A` and `B` have been erased completely.  And you can't "pass" generic type arguments to `GenFn`, so you can't directly write something like

```
type P<A extends string, B extends number> = 
  Parameters<GenFn<A, B>> // error, this is invalid TypeScript.
```

TypeScript *does* have what's called [instantiation expressions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#instantiation-expressions), where you can take a *value* of a generic function type and pass generic type arguments to it without calling it.  But you need the compiler to think you have a value of that type; it can't happen purely at the type level (as mentioned [in this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47607#issuecomment-1058192563) on [microsoft/TypeScript#47607](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47607)):

```
declare const genFn: GenFn; // pretend we have a value of this type
type P<A extends string, B extends number> = Parameters<typeof genFn<A, B>>;
// type P<A extends string, B extends number> = [a: A, b: B]
```

---

So we could look up the `get()` and `post()` method signatures of `AxiosInstance` as defined in [the `index.d.ts` file from axios](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/21a5ad34c4a5956d81d338059ac0dd34a19ed094/index.d.ts#L482-L486), which are

```
class Axios {
  get<T = any, R = AxiosResponse<T>, D = any>(
    url: string, config?: AxiosRequestConfig<D>
  ): Promise<R>;

  post<T = any, R = AxiosResponse<T>, D = any>(
    url: string, data?: D, config?: AxiosRequestConfig<D>
  ): Promise<R>;
}
```

And then pretend to make a dummy instance `_dummyAxios` of `AxiosInstance` and use instantiation parameters like `typeof _dummyAxios.get<T, R, D>`, like this:

```
declare const _dummyAxios: AxiosInstance; // pretend

class Client {
  axios!: AxiosInstance;

  get<T = any, R = AxiosResponse<T>, D = any>(
    ...args: Parameters<typeof _dummyAxios.get<T, R, D>>
  ) {
    return this.axios.get<T, R, D>(...args);
  }

  post<T = any, R = AxiosResponse<T>, D = any>(
    ...args: Parameters<typeof _dummyAxios.post<T, R, D>>
  ) {
    return this.axios.post<T, R, D>(...args);
  }
}
```

And that works.

---

But it's not a wonderful approach.  You still need to consult the Axios typings in order to determine the number, constraints, and [defaults](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) of the type parameters (i.e., `<T = any, R = AxiosResponse<T>, D = any>`) because there are no higher order type operations to give those to you.  And you have to *pretend* to have `_dummyAxios`.  It would be nice if you could at least use `typeof this.axios` instead of `typeof _dummyAxios`, but `this` isn't allowed to appear there.  And even `...args: Parameters<typeof this.axios.post<T, R, D>>` isn't particularly helpful as documentation.

Since you need to copy some things from the Axios call signatures anyway, you might as well just copy the full call signatures and use them without trying to force the compiler to perform type operations it can only sort of achieve.  That is, just copy and paste the call signatures:

```
class Client {
  axios!: AxiosInstance;

  get<T = any, R = AxiosResponse<T>, D = any>(
    url: string, config?: AxiosRequestConfig<D>
  ) {
    return this.axios.get<T, R, D>(url, config);
  }

  post<T = any, R = AxiosResponse<T>, D = any>(
    url: string, data?: D, config?: AxiosRequestConfig<D>
  ) {
    return this.axios.post<T, R, D>(url, data, config);
  }
}
```

Yes, it's more tedious for you when you're writing it, but it's a lot more straightforward for you when you're reading it, or others who come later. It's much more obvious what this code expects as input, and much easier to explain than anything involving "instantiation expressions on phantom generic functions".

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAQQB7AgZwDRwN5xgTzAFNEV0BJAOzRgENKBjIrA4uKmIqS2gG2VRoASkQCOAVyI0AwhEoAzYAHMWhEgPQi0kaszxrSgkRKkxZC5XAC+ceVAgg4Aclpk0TgNwAoLzxBSwWiY4ACkGPgAvHB8vOH02AHEiSgAxSjgAXjgAHgQ4IiROSgATNDgaKGBKFTgAIXzC5NK4SnEQACMuAD4ACloALkQsdsHagEpMrrgAbQQsWoBdbziAehX4kgAFTLhN2ihaf04oNGyk1Mou5bg1jd2d6YHymErq4cHWjq4FuEBeDcAiPZ8cWKRAYvH2JAYchocCUyTSg3OaQ8N3WYCgRCKxTgAHcSAALWgANxItDgRL4kjgEHkeHxwDKrCIsTum1yDSxZQqVRq9QKnJabU6UCmWT2ByOXFOTJpsPhlFy8y6VxZtyZu3Z-KaXJePPmHO1gq+IoeTzmcBGdR+v0AsjsxVbrSgQEEAfRAzvEvCkK1cghWVRBSAAdMUgzA0KqAFRymDZAAqO3o+CwQh2GmEAWhRHjXSwABFE5R8L1xFBeINuW84FCLEoAPyDdPGSQyOSKJTZPNdMaDTb2EAM7NCK5wSMrKNwSA0eOF5NwVNZJuZ3Q5-Ozktliu6qvFWh0BtwPNYGvtg9Lkyt2ud7u9-uD7LDlFjoEtQ4BIIkKg0egwYB71CUAAokg6JSGgAFlNgL7AqC4IYtW0LwC6xRtCA+Dpo2bhfnQjBEN4LJxGCtBoGU0i8MAyTwFBcQ0XAvroAAhJhgjYfQTD4bRcRwrGCZZEmKZpm4Wg6Gg2Zxrmh7rj0BGcUGcn7EoaC9vsb7HNKaiyshqHoW4QbcfGKb5sqMlxBM1GcXEGIwKW6QwPSaBBvRDn6XGhmHr0cmOVAiljNctFWNBNFTjxs4CYuQnLqJq6SXxRa9CZNGeQpSm7CpkonNkMq0lpIBoemQbBQZ85GV0CVmQllmYjZdIMo5umFa5xXuT0SXeWgvkJQF-ksgFLJ+O+wQhOINAiDilScOQVEyURJFwGRFGUFNFlOUxhgUNQOHsYFXGYjOsVzgua0ZtoWbRQW+3xRZcSluWzyvDUJ7KGeEUXmYbbKNeZXRFdcBWdVdm1U5em7Y1QhGT0N3Hu9SgdRZvUWQ1oXzoJRiRWJEnnXRcXST9N1bvdWC7vugxHghtbPajr3mO2n0WeVP1-dwNUOUDDVuV2ENloTe60FDtaw5xXU0fD1heFYQA)

Comment: Thank you for your time and your very thorough explanation; it has helped me tremendously! I’ve gone with your last suggestion — copying the full call signature from Axios.